# Symbol for contraction / interior product?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How to make the symbols for [interior product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InteriorProduct.html) (a.k.a. contraction)? The best I've been able to come up with is `\mathrel{\llcorner}` (or `\lrcorner`). Any other suggestions?

Comment: Martin's answer was not satisfactory for me. The resulting symbol does not match the interior product symbol I'm familiar with from my texts. The symbol should be fairly large, outlining the bottom-most and right-most edge of the glyph's rendering box. Can anyone give another answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MnSymbol](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mnsymbol/) package has `\invneg` symbol, which is most likely what you're looking for. Hope this helps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mnsymbol}

\begin{document}
\[\invneg\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, detexify wasn't able to recognize this particular symbol, nor did it suggest anything even remotely similar. It can be found, however, in the CTAN comprehensive symbol list.

Comment: I know, I tried detexify too! Anyway, \invneg and \invbackneg look fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Load the package `MnSymbol` in the preamble at the top of your tex file:

`\usepackage{MnSymbol}`

then in your body you can use:

`\righthalfcup`

See http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf for more

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for

```
\rfloor
```

as in

```
X\rfloor\alpha
```

Comment: Not quite. The contraction symbol has a long horizontal line and a short vertical line, whereas the floor symbol is the other way arund...