# Lower right corner symbol – like _|

Tags: math-mode, symbols

What is the code for the symbol "_|" in the picture below?

[image: math equation that shows desired symbol]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it’s `\lrcorner` from `amssymb`

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[\oint v_\lrcorner \dots \]

\verb|\lrcorner| $\lrcorner$

\verb|\llcorner| $\llcorner$

\verb|\urcorner| $\urcorner$

\verb|\ulcorner| $\ulcorner$
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

I found it in the LaTeX symbol list, cf. [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/4918)

Comment: Heh... Just figured it out from the big list now. :(

Comment: @KannappanSampath That's why we insist on asking the users to pose the questions properly. It might sound snobbish at first sight but it makes sure that effort and time of our answerers don't get wasted. Please persuade more next time :-)

Answer (score 6):

The third and possibly the last edit:

The four AMS delimiters in the same order as they appear in the picture: `\ulcorner`;`\urcorner`;`\llcorner`and `\lrcorner` : [image]